# Will particles with negative mass and ordinary mass annihilate when they meet?

Tags: particle-physics, mass

I know that when matter and anti-matter meet, they annihilate each other. My question is, what happens when particles with negative mass and ordinary mass meet?

Comment: To reopen this question (v2), consider to specify the nature of the negative mass: Are you talking about negative [effective mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_mass_(solid-state_physics))? Note that negative fundamental mass is off-topic as non-mainstream.